# How can i avoid parseInt function to remove leading zero's of 14th Digit Number

Tags: javascript

**I have 14 Digit Number with the leading zero's , but when i am doing parseInt on that then it is removing leading zero's.**

```
var number = parseInt("00000011121314");
console.log("Number after parsing is "+ number);
```

It is giving me answer as a 11121314 instead of 00000011121314..

Comment: because there is no such number like `00000011121314`

Comment: How did you solve this in the end?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that "00000011121314" is not actually a number, „11121314“ is. The `parseInt()` function cuts the leading zeros to convert the string, which would allow for storing leading zeros, as a string is only an array of characters. If you need to store or work with the leading zeros, you could use a string, if you can live without them and you can use integer for storing.

To be clear: there is no way to store leading zeros in an integer, as the datatype was constructed to handle numbers.